# Custom environment to create table-like matrix

Tags: tables, math-mode, matrices

I like to set up a custom environment `tabularmatrix` such that I use it in the math mode as follows:

```
\[
\begin{tabularmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
\end{tabularmatrix}
\]
```

My desired output from it should be as same as obtained from:

```
\[
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
    \hline
    $d$ & $e$ & $f$ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\]
```

How should I optimally define the custom command `tabularmatrix`?

Comment: Have a look at `tabluarray` which allows using `key-val` settings easily.

Comment: As an aside, instead of using `tabular` inside math mode and all those `$` use the `array` environment directly. It is almost the same as `tabular` but uses math mode for its cells.

Answer (score 5):

Quite simple with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tabularmatrix}{+b}{
    \begin{tblr}{
       hlines, vlines, columns={c},
       rowsep=0.1pt, colsep=5pt,
       }
    #1
    \end{tblr}
    }{}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabularmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
\end{tabularmatrix}
\quad
\begin{tabularmatrix}
  it & works & with & any \\
  number & of & rows & or \\
  columns & a & b & c \\
  d & e & f & g
\end{tabularmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OP uses centered columns: `columns = c`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You're right, I've updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I find it really nice for the simplicity. But the dimensions of cell boxes are appearing comparatively bigger than the ones in the output of @egreg's answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686197/114006.

Comment: @raf You can choose the row and column separators as you wish, see my renewed answer. (You can also choose the width and the height of the cells, see `wd` and `ht` options of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray))

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot for your update.

Comment: @raf You're welcome, `tabularray` is very customizable :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to nest arrays or other objects using `\\`, you can do it as follows. Any number of columns are accepted, as long as they're at most `MaxMatrixCols`, like for `matrix` in `amsmath`; increase the counter's value if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{cagedmatrix}{b}
 {
  % split the input at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % check for a missing trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl }
  % build the array, inserting \\ \hline between rows
  \array{|*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{c|}}\hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ \hline }
  % finish up
  \\ \hline
  \endarray
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cagedmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
\end{cagedmatrix}
\quad
\begin{cagedmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f 
\end{cagedmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may possibly be interested in `ytableau`, though.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the excellent package `ytableau` too.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly a solution since it doesn't use your preferred name for the environment, but you can use `nicematrix`. You must compile twice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceArray}{*{3}{c}}[hvlines]
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the answer of @CarLaTeX to produce a dedicated environment.